# Is there way to set image file in input field using jquery?

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, image-processing, jquery-file-upload

I can compress image but can't upload compress image through ajax.
my preview image is compress, but how to send it through ajax post request.

I make input field in form and I want to select compress image to that input field. so that compress image can upload through it. But I don't know how to do it? I searched lot from 3 days but didn't find any help.

**Or** if its there any other ways to upload compress image please tell.

`HTML`

```
{{ form.image|as_crispy_field }} //form imagefield has id=file  
<form action="home_page/mainpost/post/" id="mainpost-form"  enctype="multipart/form-data" class="shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
 
  <input id="img-hidden" name="image" accept="image/*" type="file"  style="display:none"> 
  {{ form.info_post|as_crispy_field }}
  Preview Image - <br>
  <div class="hidden-img-div">
    <img id="original-Img"/>
  </div>
      <br>
  <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value='Post'>
</form>
```

`Jquery`

```
<script>
  document.getElementById("file").addEventListener("change", function (event) {
    compress(event);
  });
  function compress(e){
    const width = 300;
    const fileName = e.target.files[0].name;
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
    reader.onload = event => {
        const img = new Image();
        img.src = event.target.result;
        img.onload = () => {
                const elem = document.createElement('canvas');
                const scaleFactor = width / img.width;
                elem.width = width;
                elem.height = img.height * scaleFactor;
                const ctx = elem.getContext('2d');
                // img.width and img.height will contain the original dimensions
                ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, img.height * scaleFactor);
                ctx.canvas.toBlob((blob) => {
                    const file = new File([blob], fileName,{
                        type: 'image/jpeg',
                        lastModified: Date.now()
                    });
                }, 'image/jpeg', 0.8);
              document.getElementById("original-Img").src = elem.toDataURL();
            },
            reader.onerror = error => console.log(error);
    }
  }    
$("mainpost-form").on("submit",function(e){
  e.preventDefault
  $.ajax(
    { 
      type:"POST", 
      url: "home_page/mainpost/post/", 
      data:{ csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}"},
      dataType: 'json', 
    })
    .done(function(response){
    console.log(response)
    });
});
  </script>
```

**Please help** thank you

Comment: why your `ajax.data` only submitted `csrftoken`?

Comment: @minglyu because at the time form submitting without variable  can pass data. I can access data with variable with name of input field.

Comment: `e.preventDefault` has prevented the data submission, you need to submit the form data again in the `ajax.data`, `print(request.POST)` in server to see what happens.

Comment: @minglyu without this also I can get data.. I can see in terminal. I also did as you told the same thing only `post_info` get but image. . My question is how to send preview image through ajax. I created one input field so that  I can pass image through it.  how to do it or any other method please tell . thank you

Comment: @minglyu  the problem is not in data. I want to send preview compress image through ajax how to do it?